# Blank page obtained when trying to upload a background on a Webpage using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a webpage with an image as background. However, I don't succeed to have an image as background. I obtain a blank white page. The "images" folder is in the same folder as my HTML and CSS files, and the image is named "banner.png".

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

I have tried multiple things, like making sure my syntax is fine and I have tried different image sizes.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header{
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30, 0.7), url(images/banner.png));
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <section class="header">

 </section>
```

Comment: Have you used your browsers devtools inspect facility to see what CSS is actually being applied? You should see that linear gradient is not valid.

Comment: @PhilippeRobert Put code in the question, instead of linked images of code

Comment: @AHaworth No I haven't used it, I wasn't aware it existed. I just looked into it and I will definitely use it next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. For linear gradient to work, you have to **provide two color stops**. You have provided only one.
2. Secondly, write the **image path in url() in double quotes**.

Here is the updated code:-

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header{
   min-height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30, 0.7), rgba(4,9,30, 0.7)), url("https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300");
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <section class="header">

 </section>
```

I have used the dummy image link in my code, you can update it with your image path.

Comment: @PhilippeRobert My pleasure. Mark the answer correct for future visitors.